# How To find Login event in MacOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to get notifications during user login and logout events programmatically. As of now I could figure out the logout events by using `NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification` but not able to figure out the way to receive the login events.

Please let me know the way to get the Login event programmatically.

Comment: See AppleScript's Dictionary.

Comment: can you please provide the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I did spend some time to look into it , like you said i was unable to find anything that suggest that it "powered on" . However there were some behaviours such as `NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification` and `NSWorkspaceScreensDidWakeNotification` to identify screen waking up and screen power . Take alook at the documentation of Apple below Make your way down to the "notifications" section

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace?language=objc